# Why can't anybody that shares the president's name claim to have been elected?

Tags: united-states, president, presidential-election

Let's say I change my name to Donald Trump and declare my intent to run for President. If Trump is re-elected, why do I not have just as much as a claim to the presidency as him? The ballot doesn't put his SSN and it doesn't put his picture. Why can't anyone with his name declare it was actually *them* who was elected?

Comment: I'm pretty sure if there were ever two presidential candidates with the exact same name, they'd figure out a way to differentiate them on the ballot. And that is whats relevant, because without being a candidate and being on the ballot, you have no claim to victory.

Comment: But why do they even need to appear on the ballot? Why can't I claim that I was the person elected when people cast their votes for the candidate on the ballot if we share the same name?

Comment: Because you have no proof whatsoever. You don't have any of the paperwork associated with the process. And presumably, somewhere in the whole process your identity is checked. A name is just that, a name. its not an identity.

Comment: But on the ballot is simply a name, not an identity

Comment: And...? I fail to see how that matters, since you elect a *person*, not a name.

Comment: @AlecAlameddine, the ballot paper in the polling booth is simply *one* representation of a complex legal and political process. As Polygnome mentioned, steps would be taken if there was ever any doubt that the name "Ronald Reagan" could have referred to someone otherr than the former California governor.

Comment: Why don't you try it and let us know the results?

Comment: For starters, at least in Maryland you would need to change your name to Donald J. Trump and be a resident of New York as all of that is on the ballot. Next, if you attempted to change your name to that it might not be accepted if it appeared you were changing your name for the intent to deceive, interfere, or create confusion.

Comment: I think this is a worthwhile question, if for no other reason than that the US allows write-in candidates for at least some of its elections. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-in_candidate

Comment: Am I the only one picturing big queues outside the White House every four years of hundreds of people with the same name while they try and work out which one of them should be President?!

Comment: I'm not going to write this as an answer, but seriously: one can't do this for the same reason that other people named Donald Trump cannot withdraw money from Donald Trump's bank accounts. It's fraud, pure and simple, subject to heavy fines and jail rime.

Comment: In a similar vein I’ve often wondered given the caliber of the current president if a cantaloupe could be elected.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because you have no proof whatsoever to being the elected *person*.

There is a lot of paperwork associated with becoming a candidate and appearing on the ballot. Paperwork only the actual person who was elected would have access to.

> An individual running for a seat in the House or Senate or for the office of U.S. President becomes a candidate when he or she raises or spends more than $5,000 in contributions or expenditures. [...]
> All such candidates must register with a Statement of Candidacy (Form 2) and designate a principal campaign committee within 15 days of becoming a candidate as described. Candidates (including incumbents) must file a Statement of Candidacy for each election cycle in which they are candidates.
>
> All candidates file with the FEC, electronically or by paper.
>
> Candidates who file electronically are required to use Form 2. Candidates who file by paper can use either Form 2 or a letter with the same information that’s captured on Form 2.
>
> The Statement of Candidacy requires a candidate’s signature. It collects some basic information, including the candidate's name and address. It’s also where candidates authorize any campaign committees working for them.

[Source](https://www.fec.gov/help-candidates-and-committees/registering-candidate/house-senate-president-candidate-registration/)

The actual candidate would have access to all this paperwork and could easily prove that it was them, not you, who filed these papers and was the candidate/on the ballot.

I am pretty sure that if the situation ever arises that two presidential candidates have the same name, the FEC would find a way to make in *unambiguously clear on the ballot* who is who. A name is just one of the many ways to represent a person ([and a a bad one at that](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)).

Comment: I was reading the state level requirements on ballotpedia, and a lot of them are just that the party writes to the Secretary of State and says Donald Trump's their candidate (plus a list of electors). If the party decided they'd picked the wrong Donald Trump, it seems possible they could replace him with another.

Comment: The FEC isn't responsible for the ballots; each state is.

Comment: A duplicate name situation [almost happened in CA-36's House election](https://www.politico.com/states/california/story/2019/09/05/california-democrat-raul-ruiz-faces-a-challenge-from-raul-ruiz-1172209), until one of the Raul Ruizes withdrew from the primary.

Answer (score 2):

> But on the ballot is simply a name, not an identity.

The ballot typically has the candidate's name **and party**.  So if “Donald J. Trump **(Republican Party)**” wins the election, any confusion could be cleared up by contacting the Republican National Committee and asking *which* Donald J. Trump that is.  And they will have a paper trail backing up the claim of a particular man born on June 14, 1946 in New York City.

(Incidentally, I happen to have a name very similar to a Congressman.  I've joked to my family and co-workers about winning “my” election, but left it at that.)

Comment: Also, for presidential elections, the Electoral Collage does the actual electing. They are pretty unlikely to assume those votes are for the less famous person with that name.

Answer (score -1):

In a comment, you wrote

> But on the ballot is simply a name, not an identity.

A name *is* an identity.  The name is on the ballot for the sole purpose of identifying an individual.

If two people with the same name claim to have been elected to the same office, there is a mechanism for identifying the correct individual.  In the case of the US presidency, the body responsible for such questions is the United States Congress.  In the case of the current crop of candidates, there is no ambiguity: each name on every ballot identifies a single individual.